# Cannot select linesegment in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Drawing a baseline in an attempt to make a grid. Have managed to draw baseline but cannot select using cad tools "select one linesegment" tool. Worked previously and I'm not aware that I'm doing anything different.

Baseline was made using this process:
Layer -> create layer -> new shapefile layer (line button checked, correct CRS) -> toggle editing -> add feature tool -> create two vector points to make a line -> Save Layer Edits

After this I try to select and it just doesn't register. Can select using the "select features by area or single click" tool but cannot create parallel lines using this (which is what I'm trying to do).

Possibly a bug, submitted a ticket for it at 13:05 GMT 09-07-15 will update if get response.

Comment: This seems like a bug. I can use the _Select Line Segment_ tool in QGIS 2.6.1, but not on QGIS 2.8.2. Which QGIS versions are you using?

Comment: QGIS 2.8.2. I managed to use the _Select Line Segment_ tool in 2.6.1. I was wondering if the method had changed. I only downloaded onto this pc yesterday, I briefly looked for a 2.6.1. download since I thought that version might be more stable.

Comment: You could consider opening a [ticket](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) to report this for not working in QGIS 2.8.2. Personally, I still work with QGIS 2.6 but take note of the various plugin versions as some might have to be downgraded if they were updated for QGIS 2.8 =)

Comment: I've submitted a ticket, have found a way to work around the issue by making a regular grid then deleting the sections I don't need. Might go and download 2.6 soon though.

Comment: Great that you submitted a ticket! Atleast you found a workaround though, hopefully your work flow won't be too much affected :)